# C++ operator overloading, operator bool() and operator !()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I have overloaded `operator bool()`. Do I need to overload `operator !()` too? When and why. Thanks for help.

Comment: When there's more than one user-defined conversion maybe, but that's easily fixed without doing that.

Comment: See also this stack overflow question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/what-is-the-meaning-of-operator-bool-const-in-c

Comment: this article about using operator bool and operator ! may also be helpful.  http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should also implement `operator!()` if you want a developer to be able to say `!myobject` where `myobject` is an instance of your class.

Section 13.3.1.2 specifies that when applying a unary operator to an object of user-defined type

> the built-in candidates include all of the candidate operator functions deﬁned
>   in 13.6 that, compared to the given operator,
>
> - have the same operator name, and
> - accept the same number of operands, and
> - accept operand types to which the given operand or operands can be converted according to
>     13.3.3.1, and
> - do not have the same parameter-type-list as any non-template non-member candidate.

So the compiler may use the built-in `bool operator!(bool)` and your user-defined conversion, but only when your `operator bool()` is implicitly callable.  `operator bool()` is almost always made explicit to avoid its use in arbitrary integer contexts.  Multiple user-defined conversions could also create ambiguity among built-in candidate operators as chris mentioned in a comment.

So it's best to just define `operator!()` yourself.

Comment: thx @leftroundabout, I messed up the formatting there and didn't even notice