# What overloaded operator is called in an if condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement

From the example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/ there is the following statement

```
ifstream is;
...
...

if (is) { // What overloaded operater of **is** object is called here
....
}
```

What overloaded operator of **is** object is called ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of "operator bool() const" in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/what-is-the-meaning-of-operator-bool-const-in-c)

Comment: @volerag: Only if you already know the answer of the question -- "What overloaded operator is called" -- "`operator bool()`". Thus, the link is related, but the question is not duplicate.

Comment: Well, @DevSolar I think I answered his question *as well as* called it duplicate. Nothing wrong in that, right?

Answer (score 6):

Since C++11, there is a conversion operator to `bool`:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

Before that, there was a conversion operator to `void*`:

```
operator void*() const;
```

the latter evaluates to `true` for any non-null pointer and `false` otherwise.

Comment: And it's worth noting, that if you are writing code where you can't use `operator bool()`, you should read up on the safe bool idiom.

Answer (score 2):

The [`bool` conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) of `std::basic_ios`.

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
if ( ! is.fail() )
```