# What is the relevance of if (!(cin >> variableName)) in this loop

Tags: c++, loops, random, do-while

I'm a self taught developer trying to learn c++, I found this exercise on google and I wrote the code for it, though all my conditions were correct, it wouldn't work, when I checked their answer, I found this line of code- if (!(cin >> guess)). I honestly don't see the relevance, I don't know why it made my loop not to work. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])    
{

int nUserRandNum = 0;
    int randomNumber=0;

    srand (time(NULL));
    randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;

    printf("Please enter a random number between 1 - 99 \n");

    scanf("%d", &nUserRandNum);


    do
    {
        if (randomNumber < nUserRandNum)
        {
            printf("Try to go a little higher than \n", nUserRandNum);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You might want to go a little lower than \n", nUserRandNum);    
        }
    }
    while (randomNumber != nUserRandNum);

    printf("You got it!!!");

    system("Pause"); 

    return 0;
}
```

When I checked the answer they had:

```
int random_number, guess;

// Initialize random seed.
srand (time(NULL));

// Generate random number between 1 and 100
random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;

cout << "Guess our number (1 to 100) ";
cin>>guess;
do 
{
    if (!(cin >> guess)) 
    {
      cout << "Please enter only numbers" << endl;
    } 
    else 
    {
      if (random_number < guess) 
          cout << "The secret number is lower than " << guess << endl;
      else if (random_number > guess) 
          cout << "The secret number is higher than " << guess << endl;
    }
} while (random_number != guess);
cout << "Congratulations!" <<  endl;
```

what does that if statement do `{if (!(cin >> guess)) }`? And are there other reasons my loop didn't work?

Comment: You don't read in answers in your loop-your user gets only a single guess.

Comment: `cin >> guess` is the input operation - it's reading the next input value from the standard input stream and storing it in `guess`.  Since you're reading into an integer variable, the operation will fail (evaluate to false) if the input string is not a valid integer constant (contains something other than digits).   If you enter something that isn't an integer, you get the `"Please enter only numbers"` message - otherwise it compares the input to the random number.

Comment: Expansion to @JohnBode 's comment on what's happening: [Why and how it happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/what-is-the-meaning-of-operator-bool-const). And more details: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `scanf` and `cin >>` is not relevant here, that's not what makes it work.

Here's what you have:

```
scanf("%d", &nUserRandNum);
do
{
    ... print ...
}
while (randomNumber != nUserRandNum);
```

Your `scanf` is outside of the loop. Therefore, when the `do`...`while` condition is satisfied, the *same number that the user already entered* is checked again.

This needs to be inside the loop body, like so:

```
do
{
    scanf("%d", &nUserRandNum);
    ... print ...
}
while (randomNumber != nUserRandNum);
```

Reading input from `cin` rather than using `scanf` is probably a good idea, as it's less easy to get wrong. (Although the code you've shown still manages to do so.)

Checking whether a number was successfully read is probably a good idea too. When the user enters random garbage, you shouldn't treat that as if the user had entered a number.

But neither of those is the cause of your problem.

Comment: <p>Oh my! I totally understand it now, because the scanf is not in the loop, he only gets to input once, so the loop goes on forever regardless. Bless you! <p> <p>Alright I'll do well to ensure that I verify that what was entered was a number before the loop runs. Thank you</p>

Answer (score 1):

You can understand that `if (!(cin >> guess))` statement as "if inputting the number was unsuccessful", so `(cin >> x)` is true if the type entered by the user really is an int.
Nitpick: you switched "go lower" with "go higher" by the way.

Comment: This only deals with about 1/3 of OP's problem. You should expand on why OP's attempt failed to work.

Comment: That was already explained by the other answer, I'm addressing the question from the title.