# What does bool operator() do?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, operator-overloading

I am not able to understand this piece of code from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-a-map-by-value-in-c-stl):

```cpp
// C++ program for the above approach
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
  
// Comparison function for sorting the
// set by increasing order of its pair's
// second value
struct comp {
    template <typename T>
  
    // Comparator function
    bool operator()(const T& l,
                    const T& r) const
    {
        if (l.second != r.second) {
            return l.second < r.second;
        }
        return l.first < r.first;
    }
};
```

I find similar article in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600295/). but all of them are little different.

I also want to ask, what is the difference between writing `bool operator ()` and `operator bool()`?

Comment: `bool operator()` is a function operator, making the instantiated object a *functor*.  But `operator bool()` is an implicit conversion operator converting the object to `bool`.

Comment: Note that [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is an awful habit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077), as is [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077). Combining them is pretty much begging for problems.

Comment: @FredLarson GeeksForGeeks is awful for that, and lots of beginned fall into the trap of trusting that site that share bad practices.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Yes, so I've gathered.

Answer (score 5):

`bool operator()` defines the operator `()` for the class instances and makes it accept two arguments to make a comparison and return a `bool`.

While `operator bool()` defines the `bool` operator i.e makes the class instances be convertible to `bool`s

---

As a summary, the first function overloads the operator `()` while the second overloads the operator `bool`

---

**An example**

Suppose you want to define a comparator and want to know if it's valid or not so you put a flag to know that, hence you have the following.

```cpp
struct Comparator{
    bool valid{};
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)const{
        return lhs<rhs;
    }
    explicit operator bool()const{
        return valid;
    }
};

int main(){
    Comparator x{true};
    std::cout <<((x) ? "x is valid": "x is not valid") << "\n";
    std::cout << "is 1 les than 2: " << std::boolalpha <<  x(1,2);
}
```

It's not a good use case but I wanted to put both operators in one class to say that they can be defined for the same class.

The `bool` operator is used with the objects that may be in an invalid state like smart pointers and `std::optional<T>` ,...

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed examples of how both operators are used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau added